# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't boot after restart: Hangs after fsck

Tags: boot, 16.04, fsck

Hello and sorry in advance if this is duplicate; I've read all other posts and still can't figure out how to fix this.

I have a Lenovo T540P with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. I use this laptop every day and have never had issues with Ubuntu. Yesterday, I restarted my laptop (it usually stays on for months at a time as I am always working on it, only suspending overnight) and now it won't boot.

The screen says

`/dev/sda1: clean, 338085/30220288 files, 8546668/120849408 blocks`

I've let it sit for like half an hour now and it just hangs. I can tty to F2 and login, but I don't know how to diagnose the problem.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to reinstall lightdm. TTY and execute the following:

`sudo service killall lightdm`

`apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`

`sudo reboot`

I don't know why this worked, but it may help others ...