# Ubuntu startup stuck on fsck loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login, lightdm, gdm

## Issue

My Ubuntu 18.04 boot is stuck in a loop switching between turning black and showing the following line:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 481726/7323648 files, 8253625/29267456 blocks.
-
```

This happens after showing the Ubuntu splash screen and before showing the login manager (gdm3).

## Failed solutions

- Running fsck in / in recovery (does not detect errors)
- The solution in [Ubuntu stuck on boot, won't get past fsck!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850670/ubuntu-stuck-on-boot-wont-get-past-fsck) (even though my thinkpad T570 only has a graphical intel chip)
- Switching to lightdm (the lightdm login screen shows, but no keyboard input is possible, not even with the onscrean keyboard).
  From [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't boot after restart: Hangs after fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851598/ubuntu-16-04-lts-wont-boot-after-restart-hangs-after-fsck)
- Running the commands from [Ubuntu 16.04 - GUI freezes on login start page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368748/ubuntu-16-04-gui-freezes-on-login-start-page)

By editing the grub entry (quiet splash -> nomodeset) I can still log into tty, where the rest of the system seems to be working.

## EDIT: Solution for the posterity

It was a typo in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc file. This typo repeatedly crashed the XServer, which made it look like it was stuck on the fsck line.

Comment: It does not appear to be a problem with fsck my guess is s problem with your graphics card. Can you boot an old kernel and identify your graphics card

Comment: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02). Obtained with ("lspci | grep VGA")

Comment: And sorry it is Ubuntu 18.04 not 16.04 (fixed in post).

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from 17.xx to 18.04? Has this problem occurred since 18.04? If so, check my question, update #7, at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot for a possible answer.

Comment: No, it was a clean 18.04 install, the problem appeared after I was booted into a windows partition and installed updates there. I tried your wayland suggestion and the only difference is that the specified line (fsck result) is printed twice.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, it is completely unrelated. Thank you for both of your time.